# Failed to save a file in azure data lake from azure data bricks

Tags: python-3.x, xml, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm trying to save the string content into azure data lake as XML content.

a string variable contains below mentioned xml content.

```
<project>
    <dateformat>dd-MM-yy</dateformat>
    <timeformat>HH:mm</timeformat>
    <useCDATA>true</useCDATA>
</project>
```

i have used the below code to process the file into data lake.

```
xmlfilewrite = "/mnt/adls/ProjectDataDecoded.xml"
with open(xmlfilewrite , "w") as f:
    f.write(project_processed_var)
```

it throws the following error:
No such file or directory: '/mnt/adls/ProjectDataDecoded.xml"

I'm able to access the data lake by using the above mounting point but unable do with the above function "open".

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Issue is solved.

In databricks when you have a mount point existing on Azure Data Lake,we need to add "/dbfs" to the path and pass it to OPEN function.
The issue is solved by using below code

```
xmlfilewrite = "/dbfs/mnt/adls/ProjectDataDecoded.xml"
with open(xmlfilewrite , "w") as f:
    f.write(project_processed_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Spark-XML library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml). Convert your string to a dataframe where each row denotes one project. Then you can write it to ADLS in this way.

```
df.select("dateformat", "timeformat","useCDATA").write \
  .format('xml') \
  .options(rowTag='project', rootTag='project') \
  .save('/mnt/adls/ProjectDataDecoded.xml')
```

Here is how you can include an external library -https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html#create-a-library

Comment: i have tried to save the \XML as suggested but it saves in a different format as shown below.
```
<ROWS>
    <project>
        <ProjectData>&lt;project&gt;
    &lt;dateformat&gt;dd-MM-yy&lt;/dateformat&gt;
    &lt;timeformat&gt;HH:mm&lt;/timeformat&gt;
    &lt;useCDATA&gt;true&lt;/useCDATA&gt;
    </ProjectData>
    </project>
</ROWS>
```
Could you please provide me how to convert the string to data frame.